# Failed to load optimized model at path error with Google Maps API using Xcode 7 / iOS9

Tags: google-places-api, swift2, ios9

I am trying to use the Google Places API autocomplete feature in my code.

```
    import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

class ViewController: UIViewController, GMSMapViewDelegate {

    var placesClient: GMSPlacesClient?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        placesClient = GMSPlacesClient()

        let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
        filter.type = GMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilter.City
        placesClient?.autocompleteQuery("Pizza", bounds: nil, filter: filter, callback: { (results, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if let error = error {
                print("Autocomplete error \(error)")
            }

            for result in results! {
                if let result = result as? GMSAutocompletePrediction {
                    print("Result \(result.attributedFullText) with placeID \(result.placeID)")
                }
            }
        })

    }
}
```

When I run it I am getting this error: `CoreData: Failed to load optimized model at path '/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/` 
Any ideas?

Comment: Seems to be an issue with iOS9/Xcode 7. Check out https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8459 && https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32233939/core-data-failed-to-load-optimized-model-at-path

Answer (score 2):

Add **-ObjC** to "`Other Linker Flags`"

```
(Build Settings -> Linking -> Other Linker Flags).
```

This solved it for me.

After I added this flag I received some errors regarding missing symbols (such as *_`CBAdvertisementDataManufacturerDataKey`*).

I added the **`Accelerate`** and **`CoreBluetooth`** frameworks in *`Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries*.`

Answer (score 1):

This issue is fixed in the new update of Google maps 
**https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/releases?hl=en**
 Check this Link and update your local repositories