# CoreData: Failed to load optimized model at path

Tags: google-maps, swift2, ios9, xcode7

I am getting this warning multiple times when i goto a view using google maps.This started as soon as i migrated to swift 2.0 and xcode 7 for my exising project .Im using google maps in my project. See the console log below [image]

I have gone through some links but was not helpful 
https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8459

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/14157

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32671696/failed-to-load-optimized-model-at-path-error-with-google-maps-api-using-xcode-7 | https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8459

Comment: My answer to a related question here might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33178033/2649021

Answer (score 3):

In my case I needed doing 1) update cocoa pod, 2) setup again, and 3) update pods.

1) `$ gem update cocoapods`

2) `$ pod setup`

3) `$ pod update`

Answer (score 2):

As indicated in your console log, this is caused by an issue in the Google Maps SDK. The issue has been fixed in the latest Google Maps SDK release, so if you update it, it should work like before.

If you're using CocoaPods, just add `pod 'GoogleMaps'` in your podfile and run `$ pod install`.