# Is there any way to hack into static framework for Swift Project?

Tags: ios, core-data, swift2, xcode7, google-maps-sdk-ios

So, plenty of issues have been posted around this like:

- [Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32233939/core-data-failed-to-load-optimized-model-at-path/32771126#32771126)
- [Google Code Issue Report](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8459).

The problem in few words is the following: GoogleMaps SDK has an error when updating to XCode 7 GM (consequently using Swift 2), because when loading the bundle resources, apparently it can't find/read the '.mom'/'.omo' file.

```
'CoreData: Failed to load optimized model at path '.../APP_NAME/GoogleMaps.bundle/GMSCacheStorage.momd/Storage.omo'
```

[This answer explains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32233939/core-data-failed-to-load-optimized-model-at-path/32771126#32771126) a workaround if I were to load the resources mannually or if using a POD, but ***my problem is that I'm linking to the static library manually to support iOS 7.x*** (long story, Pods on swift only work with dynamic libraries and iOS 7 doesn't support them, but it worked perfectly until XCode 7/Swift 2). Maybe someone knows a way to hack into the GoogleMaps.bundle inside the framework file...

I'm thinking of something like -> (right-click GoogleMaps.bundle + Show Package Contents + 'maybe change some file paths/extensions?')

Apart from the Log Error, Google Maps functionality (at least the features I'm using) work fine in the app. The problem is when uploading to the App Store, I receive an error because of this.

Comment: use old google framework if you need support legacy code

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fixed in the new update of Google maps 
**https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/releases?hl=en**
 Check this Link and update your local repositories

Comment: That sounds great, I'll check it out! I found the way to fix it in the mean time, by manually removing the troublesome file '.omo' extension inside the package contents of the bundle