# CoreData: error: Failed to load model named UnitTests

Tags: swift, xcode, unit-testing, swiftui, core-data

I am trying to run a Unit UI test with Core Data. I am getting an error:

> CoreData: error:  Failed to load model named UnitTests

How to fix this? I have searched if the question was asked but I only found old questions and/or answers that I've tried already (adding target, checking data model name).

**My purpose**: I want to use UI Tests to take screenshots for the App Store. So I want to use inMemory store and add a function that creates example data for the screenshots when I run UI Tests.

I have created a new project in Xcode, selected Core Data and include tests. Later changed just a few things. So it's based on the Core Data template project.

I noticed that **Persistence.swift** and **UnitTests.xcdatamodeld** files didn't have target memberhip selected for **Tests** and **UITests** so I added those for both.

**Persistence.swift**

```
import CoreData

struct PersistenceController {
    static let shared = PersistenceController()

    static var preview: PersistenceController = {
        let result = PersistenceController(inMemory: true)
        let viewContext = result.container.viewContext
        for _ in 0..<10 {
            let newItem = Item(context: viewContext)
            newItem.timestamp = Date()
        }
        do {
            try viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            let nsError = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
        }
        return result
    }()
    
    static let unitTest: PersistenceController = {
        let result = PersistenceController(inMemory: true)
        //empty store
        return result
    }()

    let container: NSPersistentContainer

    init(inMemory: Bool = false) {
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "UnitTests")
        if inMemory {
//            container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first!.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")
            let description = NSPersistentStoreDescription()
            description.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")
            container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [description]
        }
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
    }
}
```

**UnitTestsUITests.swift**

```
import XCTest
import CoreData

final class UnitTestsUITests: XCTestCase {
    
    var coreDataStack: PersistenceController!

    override func setUpWithError() throws {
        // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.
        super.setUp()
        coreDataStack = PersistenceController.unitTest

        // In UI tests it is usually best to stop immediately when a failure occurs.
        continueAfterFailure = false

        // In UI tests it’s important to set the initial state - such as interface orientation - required for your tests before they run. The setUp method is a good place to do this.
    }

    override func tearDownWithError() throws {
        // Put teardown code here. This method is called after the invocation of each test method in the class.
        super.tearDown()
        coreDataStack = nil
    }

    func testExample() throws {
        // UI tests must launch the application that they test.
        let app = XCUIApplication()
        app.launch()
        
        func testAddNote() {
            let context = coreDataStack.container.viewContext
            
            let item = Item(context: context)
            item.timestamp = Date()
            
            XCTAssertNotNil(item, "note should not be nil")
        }

        // Use XCTAssert and related functions to verify your tests produce the correct results.
    }

//    func testLaunchPerformance() throws {
//        if #available(macOS 10.15, iOS 13.0, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 7.0, *) {
//            // This measures how long it takes to launch your application.
//            measure(metrics: [XCTApplicationLaunchMetric()]) {
//                XCUIApplication().launch()
//            }
//        }
//    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need a Core Data stack in your tests. The stack should stay in the app, otherwise you aren't testing the app code you're testing your test code.

Comment: @theMikeSwan I am sorry, I don't understand. I want to run some tests (also utilize UI tests to take app screenshots). For this I want to use inMemory Core Data and url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null") so the data is only created for the tests.

Comment: You need to load your model: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32233939/core-data-failed-to-load-optimized-model-at-path

Comment: If you want to use an in memory store for UITests you need to use something like `app.launchArguments = ["enable-testing"]` between `let app = XCUIApplication()` and `app.launch()`. Then in the app's code you make a check for the environment variable to decide if you should be using a normal store or in memory one.

Comment: UI Tests do not have access to the app's code at all. The UI tests are basically a robot user for your app. They can only interact with the same controls as a user would, the UI test code just tells the robot where to tap, swipe, etc.

Comment: Thank you @Larme I read the question and answers you linked , but to be honest I don't understand at all how to load the model. Isn't it loaded already with container.loadPersistentStores ?

Comment: @theMikeSwan so you mean I need to add this launchArguments in UITests and a condition in the app's PersistenceController that checks if the launchArguments is true? If so, use inMemory option?

To explain my purpose - I want to use UI Tests to take screenshots for the App Store. So I want to use inMemory store and add a function that creates example data for the screenshots.

Comment: Yes, that's right.